# Compiling Spring Kerberos samples with gradle wrapper - KerberosRestTemplateTests error

Tags: spring, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

I am trying to build/compile Spring Kerberos Spnego samples project i.e. the one from here.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos

I do use Gradle wrapper to build the project, however i get an error when building i.e. the build is not passing the tests. when i run the test for example "testSpnego" it breaks always in the moment they are trying to create the context i.e.

```
context = SpringApplication.run(new Object[] { WebSecurityConfig.class, VanillaWebConfiguration.class,
        WebConfiguration.class }, new String[] { "--security.basic.enabled=true",
        "--security.user.name=username", "--security.user.password=password",
        "--serverPrincipal=" + serverPrincipal, "--serverKeytab=" + serverKeytab.getAbsolutePath() });
```

First i thought that because of the version 8 of java the tests are failing but I have tried to build those jars on Windows 7 with  with jdk 1.7.0.80 and Debian with jdk 1.8.0.91. I always get the same error i.e. that the test (all of them) in the KerberosRestTemplateTests are failing.

And here is the output from the manual test i.e. from eclipse STS.

```
   10:53:22,972  INFO main runner.RemoteTestRunner - Starting RemoteTestRunner on E6440 with PID 9598 (/home/tito/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.1_991173974_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/423/0/.cp started by tito in /home/tito/Projects/Kerberos/spring-security-kerberos/spring-security-kerberos-client)
    10:53:23,158  INFO main embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@74e6094b: startup date [Mon Jan 30 10:53:23 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    10:53:23,468  INFO main logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [
...
]
    10:53:23,470 ERROR main boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotations: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:166)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.isAnnotated(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:73)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.isAnnotated(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:102)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isFullConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:104)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImport(ConfigurationClassParser.java:410)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:205)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:164)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:284)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:225)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:632)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplateTests.testSpnego(KerberosRestTemplateTests.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
        at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
        at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.doProcess(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:192)
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.process(AnnotatedElementUtils.java:162)
        ... 45 more
    10:53:23,478  INFO main embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@74e6094b: startup date [Mon Jan 30 10:53:23 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    10:53:23,481  WARN main embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@74e6094b: startup date [Mon Jan 30 10:53:23 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplateTests.testSpnego(KerberosRestTemplateTests.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    10:53:23,486  WARN main embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@74e6094b: startup date [Mon Jan 30 10:53:23 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1059)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:150)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1012)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.client.KerberosRestTemplateTests.testSpnego(KerberosRestTemplateTests.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    10:53:23,489  INFO main support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2dfb885e: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,webSecurityConfig,kerberosRestTemplateTests.VanillaWebConfiguration,kerberosRestTemplateTests.WebConfiguration,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
    10:53:32,163  INFO main kdc.KdcServer - Kerberos service stopped.
    10:53:32,612  INFO main api.CacheService - clearing all the caches
```

Any help in building those is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if i put a debugging point on the context i get the exception: 
Failed to introspect annotations: class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.